# How can I start using Freestyle?

Tags: linux, freestyle, windows

Blender 2.67 is out, and one of its main features is the long-awaited Freestyle integration.

I'd like to try out Freestyle, but it doesn't appear in the "Render Engine" dropdown. I assume some assembly is required. What will I need to start using Freestyle on Windows and Linux?

Comment: Try to refrain from using version specific tags, we are still trying to figure a way of going about this, for now just specify the version in your question.

Comment: @iKlsR, I actually didn't add that tag; it was added by Dan the Man.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't appear in the render engine dropdown.

In version 2.66 it is in **Render** tab > **Post Processing** > **Freestyle**.

Thanks to [RagnarSun](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9?noredirect=1), in 2.67 (and 2.67a) it is in **Render** > **Freestyle**.

Comment: is not in 2.67a under Render->Freestyle ?

Comment: I'm in 2.66.1, and Freestyle isn't appearing anywhere in the **Post Processing** section. Did it move, or is there another reason it isn't appearing in the version found in Ubuntu's repositories?

Answer (score 4):

I did a tutorial on this recently: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3LI_MTnY7U
First five minutes answer your questions(but there are many more details on the engine later on).

When your in the Blender Internal render engine go the render panel and at the bottom check Freestyle. Then go to your render layers tab. Add a new line set and your good to go.

Cheers,
-Charles

Comment: Links to external sources are discouraged on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DantheMan - They're completely fine so long as you summarize the relevant contents so that if the link goes down, your answer has useful information.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot, exactly.