# What's the most efficient way to draw edges for an object?

Tags: edges

What's the most efficient way to draw edges for an object?
By efficient I mean quick in drawing and efficient in rendering.

Example:
Adding red edges to a box.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/how-to-solidify-edges and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/is-there-really-a-way-to-make-a-true-toon-shader-material-in-cycles/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/562/how-to-get-silhouette-with-contour-rendering-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-can-i-render-an-edge-only-mesh-as-solid-lines and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-can-i-start-using-freestyle/20#20

Answer (score 2):

A possible way to do this is to use the *Wireframe* modifier. To get the result you want, add 2 materials to your object (the first for the faces and the second for the wire edges). Set the *Pass Index* of the second material to 1 (or any other number different from 0, which is the default value for any new material):

[image: material]

Add the *Wireframe* modifier to your object, and make sure to unchek *Replace Original* and to set the correct material index in the *Material Offset* input:

[image: modifier]

The final render will be something like this:

[image: render]