# How to draw very thin line on cube?

Tags: modeling

I want to draw black and thin line on cube like this building.

[image]

I tryed loop cut, but I don't know how to add color on loop cut line.

[image]

How should I do?

Comment: you need to select all these edges and them bevel (ctrl B and drag) to give them a bit of thickness

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-can-i-start-using-freestyle and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/562/how-to-get-silhouette-with-contour-rendering-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93382/blender-for-simple-profile-diagrams https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76628/how-to-outset-from-edges-vertices

Answer (score 2):

If you want that with geometry you could do several things.
If you don't need it to be a continuous mesh you can 
duplicate the object, and apply a Skin modifier to the new object, or a *Wireframe* modifier.

With the skin modifier you need to adjust the thickness in *Edit Mode*, on the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, *Mean Radius*, X and Y.

With the *Wireframe* modifier you can just adjust it globally on the modifier.

The results are visually different so you have to see what works best for you.
You can delete some of the unwanted edges on the new object too. if you don't need all the edges.

If it needs to be a continuous mesh, then you have to go by hand making all the loops and extrudes, but unless that is really necessary, I would go with the other options.

If you don't want geometry, just UVmap it and apply a texture, an image or some nodes, like *Bricks* or even a *Colorramp*.